# iphone app private test network

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, testing

I am developing an iPhone app that relies on a custom web service I created using Ruby on Rails. I want to setup a test server on my Mac without having to change the URLs that my app is pointing to - served by the RoR service. This way I can test new features or fixed bugs more easily using the test RoR server.

I have enabled internet sharing on my Mac so I can connect with my iphone to a private wifi network. I installed dnsmasq and edited my /etc/hosts file to resolve my web service URLs to the local gateway ip. However when I use my iphone app the URLs are resolved to the production server instead of my test server (my Mac).

How do I setup dnsmasq to point to the local ip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the DNS server address on the iPhone to the IP address of your Mac?

Comment: No, I just connected to the private network and turn off 3G on my iphone

Comment: Correction, I just checked again, and my Mac IP is set automatically as the DNS for the private network in the iphone settings

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it some more I was able to get it to work. I needed to edit /opt/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf and change the 'address' tag. I also had to change my Mac ethernet settings, under advance->dns I had to add 127.0.0.1 as the first dns server. This will automatically change resolv.conf which is not meant to be edited manually on a Mac.

Comment: Interesting; I've been using Fiddler running in a Windows VM to do this kind of thing - I find it to be an infinitely flexible Swiss army knife for all kinds of network-related tests (not just redirecting to a test environment but also investigating issues, injecting error responses etc), but I'm going to have a look at your solution - I'd been looking for a simpler/less resource-hungry way to just transparently redirect to another environment..

Answer (score 0):

After reading up a bit on the Dnsmasq solution, I found a nice step-by-step guide for Mac: http://davesouth.org/stories/how-to-set-up-dnsmasq-on-snow-leopard-for-local-wildcard-domains

(although personally I use Fiddler in a Windows VM for all of this sort of thing - ask if you'd like some details on that..)